# Subtract remaining time and compare number in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code which checks col K for "Sunday" date and "Time" and compares with the numbers in Col M.

What does this code do? :

For example if the date/time in Col K is 2/5/2017 18:00:00, it should minus the remaining time left, i.e 0.6 hours for the day to get over, with the number in col M. And post subtraction if the value in Col M is >1 then it should be highlighted or if it less than 1 after subtraction then it should be colored in Red.

Problem:

1. The code doesn't color in red if the values in Col M is in the range of 1.5,1.6,1.7 etc..Only if it exceeds >= 2, it starts coloring in Red..How do i fix this?
2. Currently there are two procedure defined for Pass and Fail. How do i combine this?

   ```
   Sub MinusSunday()
   Dim r, LastRow, RemainingDay As Double

   LastRow = Range("M:O").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      For r = 2 To LastRow
         RemainingDay = 0

       If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then
               RemainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(Range("K" & r)), "h")) / 24, 1)

            If InStr(1, Range("O" & r).Text, "Pass", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                If Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1 Then
                    Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Else
                    Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                End If

          End If
       End If
       Next r


        For r = 2 To LastRow
         RemainingDay = 0

       If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then
               RemainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(Range("K" & r)), "h")) / 24, 1)

            If InStr(1, Range("O" & r).Text, "Fail", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                If Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1 Then
                    Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Else
                    Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                End If

          End If
       End If
          Next r
         End Sub
   ```

Comment: Wait, you say *`2/5/2017 18:00:00` the remaining time left, i.e 0.6 hours* ? 6 hours not 0.6 hours, no?

Comment: @stack mark  even if "Pass" or "Fail" you want to color the cell in column M to be red if more than 1 hour remaining for the day ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the calculation of `RemainingDay`. What unit is it? What is exactly in column M? An example of Data and calc would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RemainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(Range("K" & r).Value), "h")) / 24, 1)` returns a value remaining of the day from 0 to 1 (your example returns 0.2).

So when running it, if the value in Column M >= 1.3, it will color the font in that cell in Red.

I've a `Select Case` with a little "trick" to combine both of your procedures.

**Note**: Since you are using `RemainingDay` to get the value of remaining time of the day in fraction (from 0 to 1), you could just use:

```
RemainingDay = 1 - TimeValue(Range("K" & r).Value)
```

(This is not currently implemented in the code, waiting for PO feedback).

To get the `RemainingDay`  in hours, you could use:

```
RemainingDay = 24 * (1 - TimeValue(Range("K" & r).Value))
```

---

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MinusSunday()

Dim r As Long, LastRow As Long, RemainingDay As Double

With Worksheets("Latency")
    LastRow = .Range("M:O").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For r = 2 To LastRow
        RemainingDay = 0

        If Weekday(.Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then
            ' returns the RemainindDay value in part of days (rounded)
            RemainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(.Range("K" & r).Value), "h")) / 24, 1)                                              
            ' Use Select case "Trick" for both cases
            Select Case True
                Case .Range("O" & r).Text Like "Pass", .Range("O" & r).Text Like "Fail"                    
                    ' ===== Line below Just for DEBUG =====
                    .Range("L" & r).Value = .Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay

                    If .Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1 Then
                        .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    Else
                        .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                    End If

                Case Else
                    ' currently do Nothing, maybe for the future ?

            End Select
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Running this code returns the following result (see debug I've added in Column "L"):

[image]

Comment: How did you get to understand that calculation. Bravo! :P

Comment: BTW it seems to me that the `Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(Range("K" & r).Value), "h")) / 24, 1)` there has to be something simpler to do it. Only a guess, I dont have a clue what it does.

Comment: @A.S.H just rounds the number of digits after the `0`, instead of getting `0.25` the result is `0.2`. not sure it's needed here

Comment: Awesome it works!! jUst one concern..the code runs when I press F5 from the editor..but the same doesn't work when I assign the macro to a button?

Comment: @stackmark is this `Sub` assigned correctly to your button ? add a `MsgBox` in the begining of the code with "Hello" and see if it's displayed

Comment: I did that and I get the message box, but the coloring is not happening...FYKI, there are multiple sheets and this code has to run on the sheet " Latency"..

Comment: @stackmark hvae you tested the edited code above ? that supports your updated info `"Latency"` sheet